# roundcube Forgot password plugin

Tags: javascript, roundcube

in the README part of the plugin https://github.com/saas-dev/roundcube-forgot_password/blob/master/README it says: To show the link "forgot my password" it necessary to activate the taskbar plugin or change the div to append the link in js/forgot_password.js
I couldn't find task bar plugin?
does any one know how should I get it ?
and also how can I change the div to append that link?
Is there any one who has used this plugin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is solved i just add a div in login page and appended the link in js/forgot_password.js like below:

there is no taskbar plugin available now !(I couldn't find any)

```
    function forgot_password(){
    if($('#rcmloginuser').val())
    {
      document.location.href = "./?_task=settings&_action=plugin.forgot_password_reset&_username=" + escape($('#rcmloginuser').val());
    }
    else
    {
      rcmail.display_message(rcmail.gettext('forgot_passworduserempty','forgot_password'),'error');
    }}$(document).ready(function($){$('#forgot-password-place').append('<a class="home" id="forgot_password" href="javascript:forgot_password();">' + rcmail.gettext('forgotpassword','forgot_password') + '</a>');});
```

this adds a link to login page for forgot password.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to how to add this,

Answer (score 0):

You can download taskbar plugin adding plugin_manager to roundcubemail

Answer (score 0):

In case it can help anyone else, and in combination with [someoneThere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3827257/someonethere)'s accepted answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25701219/9975319) which removes the need for the deprecated taskbar plugin, I've updated the forgot password plugin to work with Roundcube 1.3.8. You can fork it from my GitHub [here](https://github.com/jerryrelmore/roundcube-forgot_password).

It is still very much in an alpha state and will need to be configured for your particular Roundcube installation, but you won't have to deal w/ any forward compatibility issues/errors.

**EDIT:** Updating per suggestions in the comments below...

The original plugin has not been maintained since its release in 2011. I updated it to work with the current stable version of Roundcube (1.3.8 as of the time of this writing - Dec. 17, 2018), removing all forward-compatibility issues that I discovered during my own tests that prevented the original plugin from working on my installation. You can fork my GitHub (link above) to get the fix.

You will not have to necessarily update any of the included JS files per OP's original question, but you will still have to do more configuration than usual for a Roundcube plugin until a more stable release is pushed.